# Difference between MOV and MOV ptr

Tags: c, assembly, x86, mov

I don't understand the difference between `MOV` and `MOV ptr`.

For example, in this `C` code:

```
unsigned char x, y;
x = 2;
```

the second line in assembly is:

```
`MOV x, 2`
```

but the second line of this `C` code :

```
tabbyte[0] = 15
unsigned char tabbyte[4]
```

in assembly is :

```
MOV byte ptr tabbyte[0], 15
```

What's the difference between the two assembly instructions and when should each one be used ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 25. Directives BYTE PTR, WORD PTR, DWORD PTR
>
>     There are times when we need to assist assembler in translating references to data in memory.
>
>     For example, instruction
>
>     ```
>         mov     [ESI], al  ; Store a byte-size value in memory location pointed by ESI
>     ```
>
>     suggests that an 8-bit quantity should be moved because AL is an 8-bit register.
>
>     When instruction has no reference to operand size,
>
>     ```
>         mov     [ESI], 5   ; Error: operand must have the size specified
>     ```
>
>     To get around this instance, we must use a pointer directive, such as
>
>     ```
>         mov     BYTE PTR [ESI], 5  ; Store 8-bit value
>         mov     WORD PTR [ESI], 5  ; Store 16-bit value
>         mov     DWORD PTR [ESI], 5 ; Store 32-bit value
>     ```
>
>     These instructions require operands to be the same size.
>
>     In general, PTR operator forces expression to be treated as a pointer of specified type:
>
>     ```
>         .DATA
>         num  DWORD   0
>
>         .CODE
>         mov     ax, WORD PTR [num] ; Load a word-size value from a DWORD
>     ```

http://www.c-jump.com/CIS77/ASM/Instructions/I77_0250_ptr_pointer.htm

Comment: @gonçalocosta: This answer doesn't explain why  `MOV x, 2` is allowed:  MASM has "variables" that magically imply an operand size, when you declare them like `x dd 0` instead of regular labels like `x: dd 0`.  And also that bare symbol names are memory operands in MASM-style syntax.

Answer (score 2):

`byte ptr`, `word ptr`, etc. are only required to indicate the size to operation if it is not implied by the operands. It is the square brackets (`[` and `]`) and in MASM a bare symbol that indicates a memory reference. To use the address of a variable in MASM prefix it with `offset`, for NASM just omit the square brackets.

GNU AS in Intel syntax mode behaves like MASM in this respect.

Comment: GAS `.intel_syntax` mode will never accept `MOV x, 2` because only MASM has "variables" that magically imply an operand size, when you declare them with `x dd 0` instead of regular labels like `x: dd 0`.